# Split 1 column data to multiple column with separator as double space in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, split

Below is my record

```
13;16;AB BC  13;16;BC CD  13;16;CD DE
```

I want below result

```
|  Column 1 | Column 2  |  column 3 | 
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|  13       |        16 |    AB BC  | 
|  13       |        16 |    BC CD  |  
|  13       |        16 |    CD DE  |
```

Note: Here I want to split record with double space and then inner splitting is with (;).

Although I have three columns here, it could be more in practice. So, the solution needs to be flexible.

Comment: SQL Server honestly isn't the best place to be doing this kind of data scrubbing.  Is there any chance you could handle this before you bring the data into SQL Server, using something like R?

Comment: No, I have only SQL data.

Comment: Then you have the ability to export this data to a flat file and go from there.  This is unnormalized data and doesn't really belong in a database IMO.  If you really want to handle this in SQL Server, I think you'd need to write a custom UDF or proc.

Comment: Downvoted for: (1) begging; (2) not making an attempt; (3) causing people to waste their time by not mentioning all the constraints at the start, and then not apologising when it is pointed out. Please try to rectify these things in your future questions.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer: Thanks for drawing my attention to this 3 points but please find my justification against your point 1) Begging: I am not begging, I just want help 2) not making an attempt: I have worked out on this at least 6 hours and then I have posted this question 3) My intention is not for wasting time of others and I have found the alternative for that and work with VBA but still I want to answer for this using SQL so whenever I will get free, I will again work into this.

Comment: @ChetanSanghani if you have been attempting this for 6 hours, why didn't you include your attempt(s) in your question,or why haven't you edited your question to do so now? I *might* have saved a lot of time writing my answer if you had included that, and other volunteers will be far happier to give you other answers if you did.

Comment: @Larnu: Thanks for your effort but I will try your query and update you soon, for now, I have used alternative and it is patched thing for continues priority work but I will change it by your query after getting my result.

Comment: @ChetanSanghani put comments related to answers on the answer's comments, not the question's.

Comment: Based on the comments in my own answer, it appears that the question is considerably more unclear than any of us thought; with details only coming out in comments to answers and not being displayed in the question (the OP is still yet to address the comments here). I've therefore voted to close this question as unclear. To the OP, see the comments made, and please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Larnu: Thanks for taking action for close.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Replace` function well, with Dynamic code

```
DECLARE @X VARCHAR(100)='13;16;AB BC  13;16;BC CD  13;16;CD DE'

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)=''

SELECT @SQL = REPLACE( '
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT '''+REPLACE(@X,'  ',''' UNION ALL 
SELECT '''),';',''',''') + '''
)AS TAB(COL1,COL2,COL3)
'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Result

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
13      16      AB BC
13      16      BC CD
13      16      CD DE
```

Comment: Thanks Shakeer, But here data will not fix to 3 column, it can be more than 3 columns

Comment: You didn't mentioned it in question @ChetanSanghani

Comment: Yes,But now I am updating to you.

Comment: It will work fine for more than 3 columns also. But all sets should have same no of columns. @ChetanSanghani

Comment: But I have not same no of columns, it will be variable.

Comment: Can you please include it in your Sample data and desired output ? @ChetanSanghani

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an ideal solution, and makes some guesses based on the OP's comment on the other answer *"here data will not fix to 3 column, it can be more than 3 columns"*.

I've therefore made my own sample data and guessed. note this makes use of [delimitedsplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), so you will need it to be able to use this solution:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.StringsTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), --No idea if you have this, but sort order might be important
                               SomeString varchar(8000));

--insert sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.StringsTable (SomeString)
VALUES ('13;16;AB BC'),
       ('13;16;BC CD'),
       ('13;16;CD DE');
--Some more data, the OP says that can have strings with more (and maybe less) than 3 delimiters, but "forgot" to supply such examples...
INSERT INTO dbo.StringsTable (SomeString)
VALUES ('10'),
       ('19;124;BC CD;29;ZY XY'),
       ('29;AB CF'),
       ('43;BE HG;GY TY;18');
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.StringsTable;
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
--Get the maximum number of parts
WITH MaxParts AS(
SELECT MAX(DS.ItemNumber) AS MaxPart
FROM dbo.StringsTable ST
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(ST.SomeString,';') DS),
--Need a tally table now
N AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) V(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS i
    FROM N N1 --10
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100
         CROSS JOIN N N3 --1000
    ) --If you have more than 1000 parts then repeat, but remember, delimitedSplit8K expectes a varchar(8000), not MAX
      --Of course, also fee free to lower the number the tally returns, if it's not needed
SELECT @SQL =
       N'SELECT ' +
       STUFF((SELECT N',' + NCHAR(10) + '       MAX(CASE DS.ItemNumber WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(T.i,N'''') + N' THEN DS.Item END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('Column' + CONVERT(nvarchar(4),T.i))
              FROM Tally T
              WHERE T.i <= (SELECT MaxPart FROM MaxParts MP)
              ORDER BY t.i
              FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,9,'') + NCHAR(10) +
       N'FROM dbo.StringsTable ST' + NCHAR(10) +
       N'     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(ST.SomeString,'';'') DS' + NCHAR(10) +
       N'GROUP BY ST.ID' + NCHAR(10) + 
       N'ORDER BY ST.ID;'
PRINT @SQL; --your best friend
--Run the SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.StringsTable;
GO
```

Comment: (I've tried to update the question to note the new constraint.)

Comment: @Larnu: I have checked your solution and it has a little mistake

Comment: @ChetanSanghani would you like to share that "mistake"? That SQL, on it's own, appear to provide what was needed for your ague requirement(s) Don't forget, as many of the comments have reminded you, I basically wrote that answer blind to your requirements, as they were missing. Is it really a mistake, or are the goalposts moving (again)?

Comment: @Larnu: I have checked your solution and it has a little mistake. It give me result like Column1: 13 , Column2 : 16, Column3: AB BC  13. In column 3 there should be only AB  BC. 13 should be come in next column

Comment: @ChetanSanghani What row are you seeing that? There are no rows in my sample data that have the value `'13;16;AB BC;13'` so that value is not coming from my sample data and solution.

Comment: I am asking about my data which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ChetanSanghani I inserted the value you describe into my sample table, and it works fine (`INSERT INTO dbo.StringsTable (SomeString)
VALUES('13;16;AB BC;13');`) returns 5 columns, with values in Column 1 to 4, and `NULL` in column 5. if you have data that doesn't conform to the vague definition you have given, why aren't you providing that data?

Comment: @ChetanSanghani Your data data doesn't have an example which contains 4 items. I'm only going to repeat this once more. **Put full sample data and requirements in your question.** I am not playing the guessing game anymore.

Comment: @Larnu: Give me some time, I will update you with full data. And yes, I think there is some misunderstanding while going through my question by you. I have mentioned that first split will be done with double space then the second split should be done with (;). I think you have split only with a semicolon, that's why result getting mismatched.

Comment: I'd love to hear feedback for the downvote from whoever did it. Thanks.